# Prove that $1^n = 1, n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $1^n = 1, n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Should not be that hard, but I can't seem to solve it.

Comment: How have you defined exponentiation for real numbers?

Comment: Where in particular do you get stuck? Have you managed for a smaller set (e.g. N or Z or Q)?

Comment: not such a trivial fact. For example, $1^{1/2} \in \left\{1, \sqrt{-1}\right\}$.

Comment: What about $1^0$ ?

Comment: If you can prove it for $n \in (0, 1)$ you are done. Because you can get what you want by multiplying with necessary number of 1s, if that helps.

Comment: @gt6989b A typo: $1^{1/2} \in \{1,\color{red}{-1}\}$.

Comment: @MathLover yes, cannot fix it anymore

Comment: If $n\in\mathbb{R}$ then $n$ is the limit of a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers $\left\{r_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right\};\;a_n\in\mathbb{Z};\;,b_n\in\mathbb{N}$ for any $r_n$ the power $1^{r_n}$ is defined by $1^{a_n/b_n}=\sqrt[b_n]{1^{a_n}}=\sqrt[b_n]{1}=1$

Comment: @z100: $1^0$ is not problematic, even in $\mathbb N_0$, why would it ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust: know that, mentione just to show how important is the definition (of course, $0^0$ is more interesting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let exponentiation be some operation that is known to be distributive over division and such that $1^r\ne0$. Then

$$1^r=\left(\frac11\right)^r=\frac{1^r}{1^r}=1.$$

Comment: alternatively, it can distribute over multiplication so you get $1^r = \left(1^r\right)^2$ which implies $1^r = 1$ with the assumption $1^r \ne 0$. But yours is so much more elegant, no quadratic equations needed :)

Comment: Only missing: does such operation really exist? Otherwise, the bottom equation is defined by itself: $1^r=\frac{1^r}{1^r}$

Comment: @z100: what do you mean by "the bottom equation is defined by itself" ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust: there is no guarantee that the right side of the equation is corectly defined, if there is no correct definition (or existence) of exponentation. Anyway upvoted your answer before.  "Let the operation be" is not enough,  however maybe the strict definition and proof of limit existence is out of scope of simple OP question.

Comment: @z100: I phrased my answer this way on purpose. As the OP didn't specify his exponentiation, I gave a sufficient condition. If the exponentiation is defined and distributive, whatever it is, $1^r=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly over-complicating things but if $x = 1^r$, we must have
$$
\ln x = \ln \left(1^r\right) = r \ln 1 = r \cdot 0 = 0,
$$
which means
$$
1^r = x = e^{\ln x} = e^0 = 1.
$$

Comment: I think this likely anticipates a subsequent result in the structure of proofs

Comment: You are taking for granted that $\ln 1^r=r\ln 1$. This is probably a stronger result than the one in the OP.